# React update only one object of the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from './chart.jsx';

import Form from "./form.jsx";

import data from "./data.js";

class App extends React.Component {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.holdingArray = [];

        this.state = {
            newGraphData: "",
            startingIndex: "",
            endingIndex: "",
            form: {
                range1: {
                    month: "",
                    year: ""
                },
                range2: {
                    month: "",
                    year: ""
                }
            }
        }

        this.findIndex = this.findIndex.bind(this);
        this.generateNewData = this.generateNewData.bind(this);
        this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
    }

    findIndex(month, year) {
        var indexVal = data.findIndex(i => i.yyyy == year && i.month == month);
        return indexVal;
    }

    generateNewData(index1, index2) {
        for (var i = index1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(i <= index2){
                this.holdingArray.push({ year: parseInt(data[i].month), value: parseInt(data[i].tmax_C) });
            }
        }

        this.setState({
            newGraphData: this.holdingArray
        })
    }

    getValue(e) {
        let target = e.target,
            condition = target.name,
            value = target.value;

        switch (condition) {
          case 'range1-m':
            this.setState({
                form.range1.month: value
            })
            break;
          case 'range1-y':
            this.setState({
                form.range1.year: value
            })
            break;

          case 'range2-m':
            this.setState({
                form.range2.month: value
            })
            break;

          case 'range2-y':
            this.setState({
                form.range2.year: value
            })
            break;
        }

        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <section>
                <Chart data={dataTest} />
                <Form getValue={this.getValue} />
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

the "getValue" is called "onChange" in the following:

```
import React from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div className="form__range">
            <select onChange={this.props.getValue} name="range1-m">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
            <select onChange={this.props.getValue} name="range1-y">
              <option>1970</option>
              <option>1971</option>
              <option>1972</option>
            </select>
            <select onChange={this.props.getValue} name="range2-m">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
            </select>
            <select onChange={this.props.getValue} name="range2-y">
              <option>1973</option>
              <option>1974</option>
              <option>1975</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form__selection">

        </div>
        <div className="form__submission">
            <button onClick={this.props.submitForm}>submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Form;
```

I am getting the following error, how can it be fixed? Is it possible to update one part of the state object at the time?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `key` you want to update within the state.

```
this.setState({
  form: {
    ...this.state.form,
    range1: {
       ...this.state.form.range1,
       month: value,
    }
  }
})
```

Remember that `setState` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and therefore you won't have access to it right away.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating your state object in your `getValue` method, which is [not advisable.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Instead you should be doing the following.

```
getValue(e) {
        let target = e.target,
            condition = target.name,
            value = target.value;
           //This creates a new copy of the form object and 
           //does not change the existing object
           let newForm= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.form));
           
        switch (condition) {
          case 'range1-m':
            newForm.range1.month: value
            break;
       ...
       }
        this.setState({
                form:newForm
            })
     ...
    }
```

As an aside, you should try not have too many nested levels in the shape of your state as this leads to complexities in making changes immutably. For hints on how to normalize your state shape, advise on [managing the state shape in Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) is applicable.

**Edit:** For any concerns regarding using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to deep copy an object please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/2345964

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can go deeper than the first level of object/arrays when setting state.  Try chaning your switch function to look something more like:

```
case 'range1-m':
  const form = { ...this.state.form, range1: { ...this.state.fields.range1, month: value } }
  this.setState({ form })
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the current state with the new value.

```
var newForm = Object.assign({}, this.state.form, {
    range1: Object.assign({}, this.state.form.range1, {
        month: value
    })
});

this.setState({
    form: newForm
});
```